# SQL database with column in the tablename

Tags: mysql

I have an error in my MySQL statement (using shell file), which I can't seem to resolve. Tried to put quotes etc but no luck. When I created it using phpmyadmin it works, but I want to have it scripted. Must be something small... Any ideas?

```
--- Create mySQL database ---
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS _test-123;
CREATE USER 'test-123'@localhost IDENTIFIED BY '***';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON _test-123.* TO 'test-123'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Enter password:
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-123' at line 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the "-" and do this one instead-

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS _test_123;
```

Comment: The problem is that the domain name contains a "-" so that's what I wanted. Sure the "_" can work, but what about the "-". Could that work?

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to keep the database name after the domain? Also, have you written all of that in a single line?

Comment: I would prefer to have my tables named after my domainnames. I know the "_" could solve it, but if there is a way to keep on using "-" I would prefer that.